# AndroidStudioでテキストビューをドラッグ＆ドロップできない。

Tags: android

アンドロイドスタジオについての初歩的な質問です。
現在アンドロイドスタジオをインストールして2日の初心者です。
`Hallo world`やその他のテキストビューを配置したいのです。
しかし、水平方向についての制約に対するエラーだとは思うのですが、

> This view is not constrained horizontally: at runtime it will jump to
>   the left unless you add a horizontal constraint  The layout editor
>   allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the
>   current position with designtime attributes (such as
>   layout_editor_absoluteX). These attributes are not applied at runtime,
>   so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a
>   different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a
>   widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from
>   the edge connections.

という文がでてテキストビューをドラッグ＆ドロップできません。

よろしければ回答おねがいします。

Comment: 質問の際のタイトルは困っていることが分かる具体的な内容にして下さい。（質問一覧ではタイトルしか表示されないため内容が分からないためです。）あとビューの水平方向に対する制約が無いみたいです。何をどうやってどこまでやってビューが今どういった状態なのかわかりませんが、表示されているビューを右クリックして制約を追加すれば新しいビューを追加できるのではないでしょうか？レイアウトを計算するときの基準位置が不明なのでそうなっているのだと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。次回以降の質問の仕方も指摘してくださり助かりました。